# has_permission_on with Declarative Authorization, non attribute condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I want to give authorization to a specific action if a session variable is set in my app. I can't figure out how to do this. Something like:

```
has_permission_on :admin, :to => :action do
  true if session[:key]
end
```

I don't understand how to accomplish this basic task. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a before_filter on the function e.g.

```
before_filter :authorize, :only => :action

private
def authorize
unless session[:key]
flash[:notice] = "Cannot do this"
redirect_to(:controller => "controller", :action => "otheraction")
end
```

Comment: But this is bypassing the declarative auth completely. I just don't see the point. In my tests for example when I want to know if a user has access to a resource I should be able to do this: 

Authorization::Engine.instance.permit?(:action, :context => :controller, :object => obj )

Using the before_filter you mention I would get a false positive with the code above when checking for acces.